# how to highlight the alphabet which is used in for search using angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I need to highlight the alphabet in the searched list instead of highlighting the entire word.
Here I am filtering the `memberOffice` list and the `memberFacilities` based on the alphabet I give in search, so the entire child is getting highlighted. but now based on the filtered contents instead of highlighting the entire row, I need to highlight the particular alphabet which I had used for search, if it is more than 1 alphabet also, it needs to highlight. So basically, I need to highlight the alphabets in the filtered list based on the alphabets I had typed in the search field.
Need help.

Thanks in advance.

TS:

```
searchFacility(search) {
    this.sLetter = search;
    let memberFacilities = true;
    if (search) {
      this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = this.dtFacilities.value;
        this.dtFacilities.value.forEach(m => {
          m.memberFacilities.forEach(f => {
            let mySearch = search.toLowerCase();
            let facilityName = f.facilityName.toLowerCase();
            if (facilityName && facilityName.includes(mySearch)) {
              f.isShowMember = false;
              memberFacilities = false;
            } else {
              f.isShowMember = true;
            }
          })
        })
        if (memberFacilities) {
          this.dtFacilities.expandedRows = [];
        } 
      }, 100);

    }

  }

}
```

in HTML, I have used the

```
[class.searcHighlight]
```

I am highlighting the entire words by using this set of codes.
there is some change I need to b done but I am not getting how can that be solved.

HTML of fList:

```
<p-column field="facilityName" header="Medical Office Name" [sortable]="true">
          <ng-template let-col let-fList="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <span>
              <a (click)="selectedFacility(fList.facilityID)" [innerHtml]="fList.facilityName | getHtml : sLetter">
                <strong>{{fList.facilityName}}</strong>
              </a>
              (
              <span>{{fList.facilityType}}</span>)
            </span>
          </ng-template>
        </p-column>
DEMO:
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zp74mf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following to your code

**app.component.ts**

```
     import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
        import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'


    @Pipe({ name: 'getHtml' })
export class HighlihtText implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(value, searchText) {
    if(searchText=='' || !searchText){
      return value;
    }
    console.log("value="+value)
    var str = value.toLowerCase();
    searchText=searchText.toLowerCase();
    var currHtml = "";
    var ind = -1;
    while (str.indexOf(searchText) >= 0) {
      ind = str.indexOf(searchText);
      createHtml(value.substr(0, ind),value.substr(ind,searchText.length))
      str = str.substr(ind + searchText.length)
      value=value.substr(ind + searchText.length);
    }
    if (str.length > 0) {
      currHtml = currHtml + str;
    }
    function createHtml(nohighlighText,match) {
      console.log(nohighlighText)
      currHtml = currHtml + nohighlighText + "<span class=\"searcHighLight\" >" + match + "</span>"
    }
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(currHtml);
  }

}
```

In **app.component.html** change the part where you are highlighting the search result to

```
<a class="userlist" (click)="selectedFacility(memberFacility.facilityID)" [innerHtml]="memberFacility.facilityName | getHtml : sLetter">
                      </a>
```

In **app.module.ts** declare the newly created pipe pipe

```
import { AppComponent ,HighlihtText} from './app.component';

 declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,facilityFilterPipe,HighlihtText ],
```

For the `ALL` search issue with reset change  **app.component.ts**
add following line at the end of method **searchFacility(..)**

```
if(search==''){
      this.searchFname="";
    }
```

and  initialise variable `searchFname` as  following

```
 searchFname:String;
```

For Highligting `fList` element as well, **change**

```
<a (click)="selectedFacility(fList.facilityID)" [innerHtml]="fList.facilityName | getHtml : sLetter">
```

**To**

```
<a (click)="selectedFacility(fList.facilityID)">
                <strong  *ngIf="sLetter!=''" [innerHtml]="fList.facilityName | getHtml : sLetter"></strong>
                <strong *ngIf="sLetter==''">{{fList.facilityName}}</strong>
              </a>
```

and initialise `sLetter` in **app.component.ts** `ngOnInit()` as

```
this.sLetter="";
```

StackBlitz Url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ku9aaj

Let me know if you have any concern

Comment: HI lets talk in chat.https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192021/discussion-between-nawnit-sen-and-bhrungarajni

Comment: Hi, i have one more doubt in this, could u please help me out?

Comment: can u please help me to solve this out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55773689/how-to-display-the-child-elements-during-search-using-angular2